# how to access object in array of arrays of objects in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I did this:

```
const getData = async (array,s,number) => {
            const response = await axios.get(s);
            const theData = response.data
            array[number]=theData
        }
```

then this:

```
let array=[]
array.push(0)
getData(array, props.location.groupArray[i].link,0) //await axios.get(s) here returns an array of objects
console.log(array) //prints Array(1) 
console.log(array[0])//prints 0
console.log(array[0].length) //prints undefined
```

my question is why is array[0] here 0 and not an array of objects even though when I clck on Array(1) it shows:

```
"0: (99) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},"
```

I need array to be an array of arrays of objects, in the original code I call getData more than once with 3rd parameter 0,1,2... after I push 0 to array, my problem here is I'll only know during runtime how many axios.get I'm gonna perform thats why I wanted an array of arrays of objects

Comment: When you click in the developer console, you're seeing the value at the moment you clicked, not at the moment of the `console.log`. Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(array))` to get better insight into the value of the array at that point.

Comment: It is 0 due to the way you initialized it, and at the moment of console log it looks exactly as you declared it, array = [0]. `getData` is an async operation, array updates are happening after the axios response, which is far away in time from current code execution flow. Browser can capture the array you logged and update it in-place after it is modified. In console it will look like the initial logged array, but if you expand it - you will see the updated version.

Comment: Seems like missing `await` while making call to getData(array, props.location.groupArray[i].link,0). 
Can you try `await getData(array, props.location.groupArray[i].link,0)`?

Answer (score 0):

After you did:

```js
array.push(0)
```

The content of your array became:

```js
[0]
```

That is why accessing the first position of the array with `array[0]` returns the value `0`, and printing `array` itself returns an `Array` object with length `1` (`Array(1)`).

On the other hand, since `getData()` is an **asynchronous** function, the content of `array` remains unchanged when you use `console.log`.

So you should for example use `await` for it if your code is inside an `async` function or use `.then()` and `.catch` after the function call with `console.log` inside it to handle both Promise resolve or reject cases.

> Note: top-level await, aka calling await outside an async function, is not available yet in JavaScript, it is currently just a proposal for a future version

Comment: if that's the case, why on console when I click on Array(1) it shows an array with 99 objects in index 0?

Comment: Like @Sergey Sosunov pointed out in a comment above, the moment you are looking at the response the new result is already loaded. As I was saying before, that is the result of not handling the asynchronicity of your function.

Answer (score 0):

I think using useState is good way to set array of objects to array in this problem and use useEffect for watching result

```
const [array,setArray] = useState([0])

const getData = async (array,s,number) => {
        const response = await axios.get(s);
        const theData = response.data
        setArray(prev=>prev.push(theData)
    }
```

also,

```
useEffect(()=>{
getData(array, props.location.groupArray[i].link,0)
},[]);
```

use other useEffect for watching result

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(array)
},[array]);
```

don't forget set off StrictMode in index.js